# Using serialized ajax post data in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to get the values from multiple checkboxes via an Ajax request and use that data to filter a django object.  The problem is that when I get the checkbox data in my js file with

```
'checkboxValues' : $('#filterForm').serialize()
```

the data gets sent to the my django view as: `checks=value1&checks=value2`

I have been trying to get this data in a usable form with:

```
checkbox_values = request.POST.getlist('checkboxValues')
```

but this just returns: `[u'checks=value1&checks=value2']`

Ultimately, I need it to return `[value1, value2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news...

```
> import urlparse
> urlparse.parse_qs("checks=value1&checks=value2")
{'checks': ['value1', 'value2']}
```

(See also: [`urlparse.parse_qsl`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl), if it fits your needs better.)